# SSH Proxy (SOCKS) through remote computer - TCP & DNS

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, proxy

My problem: Need DNS to be resolved through my remote machine while also using it as a proxy.

So I have a REMOTE that I can access from LOCAL via SERVER. 
This REMOTE can access a host TARGET_HOST. TARGET_HOST is setup in REMOTE's host file like so: 123.123.123.123 TARGET_HOST

I want to be able to access (in the browser & my application) TARGET_HOST from LOCAL. I have setup a 'proxy' like so:

**LOCAL to SERVER:**
`ssh -L 4567:LOCAL:4568 user@SERVER`

**SERVER to REMOTE:**
`ssh -D 4568 user@REMOTE`

LOCAL's network config is setup to use a proxy on localhost through port 4567.

So, everything is great and I can see TARGET_HOST in my browser. The problem I have is that the DNS doesn't resolve from LOCAL and therefore some code I have going on in my application, fails. Can anyone help me? Can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: Down vote, no explanation. At least let me know what's wrong with the question.

Comment: it is very hard to read because of the massive use of boldfont and paragraphs. the actual question is not very clear, too.

Comment: Thank you, I've removed boldfont (I was hoping that would actually make it easier to read, sorry)

Comment: I've also put the problem right to the top, any help gratefully received.

Comment: have you installed a dns server on REMOTE and set it as default for LOCALs network?

Comment: No, but REMOTE can see a DNS server that LOCAL can't. If it helps, REMOTE is a client machine, not a server.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want your DNS requests to be resolved on the remote machine.  That can be done, but the returned addresses aren't guaranteed to use your ssh tunnel.  It will go out the local network.  Is that what you really want?
The easiest solution is to just hard code the address names with their ip addresses in your /etc/hosts.
The hard way is to forward the DNS requests, you'll need to modify /etc/resolv.conf to use nameserver 127.0.0.1, so that dns requests can be captured locally.
Then using ssh, you need to forward local port 53 to remote port 53.  Where remote is the ip address of the machine that can resolve your dns requests.  The problem is that you can't forward this port as non root user.  You can get around this by forwarding some random port, say 20000 to remote port 53.  Then use netcat as root to forward udp 53 to localhost 20000.

Comment: Ronan, I will give this a try but the data must go through the SSH.

Comment: If you need the data from resolved addresses to go through the tunnel, then there is no point to forward the DNS requests through port 53.  There is no easy way to do this without having to map a local port to the remote address for each host.  Why not use a vpn?  A vpn acts like a ssh tunnel but terminates as an interface so packets can be routed through it transparently.